# Does $f(z) = \frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{1}{z+1}$ have an antiderivative in $|z|>2?$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Does $f(z) = \dfrac{1}{z-1} - \dfrac{1}{z+1}$ have an antiderivative in $|z|>2?$

I know the condition for $f$ having an antiderivative is $\int_{\gamma} f(z)\,dz = 0$.

I'm not sure whether it has an antiderivative or not. I tried taking some circle $C$ in $|z|>2$ and showing $\int_{C} f(z)\,dz \neq 0$ but didn't succeed. If it does have an antiderivative, I'm not sure how to go about proving  $\int_{\gamma} f(z)\,dz = 0$ for any $\gamma$.

Comment: Yes. The residues cancel.

Comment: Show that if $\gamma$ is a path that lies in $|z| >2$ then the winding number with respect to $-1$ is the same as with respect to $+1$.

Comment: Alternately, compute the residue at infinity.

Comment: I see now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\gamma$ is a path in $\{z\in\mathbb C\mid\lvert z\rvert>2\}$, then $\operatorname{ind}(\gamma;1)=\operatorname{ind}(\gamma;-1)$. Therefore, by the residue thorem,$$\int_\gamma\frac{\mathrm dz}{z-1}-\int_\gamma\frac{\mathrm dz}{z+1}=2\pi i\bigl(\operatorname{ind}(\gamma;1)-\operatorname{ind}(\gamma;-1)\bigr)=0.$$